# Django tags auto suggest

Tags: django, django-forms, django-taggit

I use [taggit](http://django-taggit.readthedocs.org/en/latest) and I want to use [django taggit autosuggest](https://github.com/lsemel/django-taggit-autosuggest) with a custom form (no, I cannot use a ModelForm). However, no matter what I do I cannot get the autosuggestion to work in the view.

Here is my (cut down) model:

```
from taggit_autosuggest.managers import TaggableManager

class Ook(models.Model):
    tags = TaggableManager()
```

Here is my (cut down) form:

```
from taggit.forms import TagField
from taggit_autosuggest.widgets import TagAutoSuggest

class NewOokForm(forms.Form):
    #m_tags = TagField()  # This works but clearly has no autosuggestion.
    m_tags = TagField(widget=TagAutoSuggest('taggit'))  # Does not work!
```

I get no errors in the view, just no tag suggestions whatsoever.

**What am I doing wrong?**

I am using Django 1.8, the latest release at the time of the question which was/is 1.8.7.

Comment: do you receive any errors?

Comment: @SandervanLeeuwen: No errors whatsoever.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(i can't write comments so...) To clarify situation:

- provide Django version you are using, (as version of taggit-autosuggest, specified above, wont work with django 1.6+ (1.8 in my case))
- check that server side of app is working - go to http://yoursite/taggit_autosuggest/list/ - it must provide JSON list of your tags (if any) or empty list
- check that clien side is present

  - check that http://yoursite/static/jquery-autosuggest/js/jquery.autoSuggest.js available
  - check that http://yoursite/static/jquery-autosuggest/css/autoSuggest.css available

If any of files is missing, you should get it from repository.

(We assume that /static is STATIC_URL in your config)

**Upd**: Start to work when connecting Form with Model (using ModelForm ) :

```
from django.forms import ModelForm


class OokForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Ook
        fields = ['name', 'tags']
```

in views.py:

```
def OokView (request):
    form =  OokForm()
    c = {'form': form}
    return render(request,'ook_form.html', c)
```

in ook_form.html:

```
<html>
<head>
    <!-- Be sure that there is no JS errors during loading -->
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
    <link href="/static/jquery-autosuggest/css/autoSuggest-grappelli.css" type="text/css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/jquery-autosuggest/js/jquery.autoSuggest.minified.js">
    </script>
</head>

<form action="/your-name/" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>

</body>
```

Comment: I am using Django 1.8.7 which was the latest at the time I asked.

Comment: `taggit_autosuggest/list/` returns a JSON of the tags I have.

Comment: Both `js` and `css` are there and accessible.

Comment: Docs says autosuggests must works in admin interface, does it? If no, see browser console for JS errors

Comment: Yes!  That worked. I missed including `jquery-1.10.1.min.js`. A true Homer moment there. ^_~